# AWS cognito new password continuation - Android

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services

Hoping someone can help me on this, i've been trying at it for days.I'm building an Android app and integrating Amazon Cognito login. 
I am wanting to create users as admin only in Amazon Cognito using the admin panel. When doing so, one requirement is that users change their password. Within the CognitoUserPoolSignInProvider which is an anonymous class, in order to authenticate users with new passwords i have the following code in the anonymous class:

```
@Override
    public void authenticationChallenge(final ChallengeContinuation continuation) {

        if ("NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED".equals(continuation.getChallengeName())) {
            NewPasswordContinuation newPasswordContinuation = (NewPasswordContinuation) continuation;
            newPasswordContinuation.setPassword("users new password goes here");
            continuation.continueTask();
        }

    }
```

I have a separate Activity class called `ChangePassword`. This links to a User Interface and gets the input in an edit text box from the user.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_change_password);


        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newPassword);
        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);

        String pass = password.getText().toString();
```

How do i get the users input into the anonymous class to set the new password?
Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the button click callback to pull in the user password.  As your code is written now, the password will be set to an empty string (or whatever is in the EditText field at the time of creation).

Start with this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_change_password);
    final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newPassword);
    Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String pass = password.getText().toString();
        }
    });
}
```

Once you have the button click action setup, create a class instance that overrides the authenticationChallenge method. Pass that class to the appropriate AWS class for authentication.  Something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_change_password);
    final EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newPassword);
    Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String pass = password.getText().toString();
            AuthenticationHandler h = new AuthenticationHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(CognitoUserSession cognitoUserSession, CognitoDevice cognitoDevice) { }
                @Override
                public void getAuthenticationDetails(AuthenticationContinuation authenticationContinuation, String s) { }
                @Override
                public void getMFACode(MultiFactorAuthenticationContinuation multiFactorAuthenticationContinuation) { }
                @Override
                public void authenticationChallenge(ChallengeContinuation continuation) {
                    if ("NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED".equals(continuation.getChallengeName())) {
                        NewPasswordContinuation newPasswordContinuation = (NewPasswordContinuation) continuation;
                        newPasswordContinuation.setPassword(pass);
                        continuation.continueTask();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Exception e) { }
            };
            CognitoUserPool pool = new CognitoUserPool(getApplicationContext(), "poolId", "clientId", "clientSecret", Regions.US_WEST_2);
            pool.getUser("userId").getSession(h);
        }
    });
}
```